# In Windows 10, Google Music stutters when using IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-10

Today I updated to Windows 10, and now when I'm typing in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4 my music stutters in Google Music in Chrome 45.

The issue did not occur prior to the upgrade, and does not occur with Power Save mode enabled in IntelliJ. It occurs with Google Music playing using Flash, and with HTML5.

Presumably IntelliJ is aggressively taking resources for code analysis and such. Is there a way to ensure Chrome gets the resources it needs to steadily play music?

Comment: what did you try?  did you try changing the cpu slices for the programs by adjusting the priority of each?  like put the offender at an idle priority, it will still use everything left it can get hold of.  When that does not work, you can play with affinity, lock out one to 1-2 of the cores lock out the other to 1-2 of the cores, punt?  Find the windows audio service and mess with it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am experiencing the same issues with Android Studio 1.3 and Google Play music through Chrome (using HTML5 labs), and power saving mode isn't an option for me as it slows development.

I don't have a solid fix, but what has temporarily worked for me to some success is either lowering the priority of Android Studio/IntelliJ to "Below Normal" via Windows Task Manager. I haven't noticed too much of a difference to make it intolerable, but your mileage may vary according to your machine specs.

What has also worked, but to less success, is to change the priority of the process running the tab for Play music to "Above Normal", again via Task Manager. You can find the process id of the specific tab by right-clicking the top bar in Chrome and viewing Chrome's own Task Manager. I say "to less success" because I noticed the priority randomly switched back to "Normal" after a minute or so and continued stuttering.

*EDIT* Appears to work fine only in Internet Explorer, not Edge, Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, I think that solution will have to do for now. Interestingly Google Music no longer skips when my screen is off after idling for a while, which annoyed me in Windows 8. I suppose there has been some shuffling of resource utilization in Windows 10 with some unexpected side effects.

Comment: Actually, started testing other browsers, and it appears to only work fine when I play it in Internet Explorer. Same behavior in Firefox, and doesn't even load in the new Edge for me. I hate IE, but I hate stuttering music and compromising intelliJ performance more.